# CROSS/OUTER APPLY in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, cross-apply

I need to use CROSS APPLY in MySQL (EC2 RDS MySQL instance).
Looks like MySQL doesn't recognise the CROSS APPLY Syntax. Can someone help me please?

Here's the query.

```
SELECT ORD.ID
    ,ORD.NAME
    ,ORD.DATE
    ,ORD_HIST.VALUE
FROM ORD
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 ORD_HISTORY.VALUE
    FROM ORD_HISTORY
    WHERE ORD.ID = ORD_HISTORY.ID
        AND ORD.DATE <= ORD_HISTORY.DATE
    ORDER BY ORD_HISTORY.DATE DESC
    ) ORD_HIST
```

Comment: That `WHERE` clause looks questionable. Is there supposed to be an `AND` before `ORD.DATE`?

Comment: [You might want to look at this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,625014,625014#msg-625014) or [perhaps at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32894065/mysql-equivalent-to-ms-sqls-cross-apply). Best of luck.

Comment: My apologies @BobJarvis, have amended the query now.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your closest ***direct*** approximation is a join with a correlated sub-query as the predicate.

```
SELECT
   ORD.ID
  ,ORD.NAME
  ,ORD.DATE
  ,ORD_HISTORY.VALUE
FROM
  ORD
INNER JOIN
  ORD_HISTORY
    ON  ORD_HISTORY.<PRIMARY_KEY>
        =
        (SELECT ORD_HISTORY.<PRIMARY_KEY>
           FROM ORD_HISTORY
          WHERE ORD.ID = ORD_HISTORY.ID
            AND ORD.DATE <= ORD_HISTORY.DATE
       ORDER BY ORD_HISTORY.DATE DESC
          LIMIT 1
        )
```

In your case, however, you only need one field from the target table.  This means that you are able to use the correlated sub-query directly in the SELECT statement.

```
SELECT
   ORD.ID
  ,ORD.NAME
  ,ORD.DATE
  ,(SELECT ORD_HISTORY.VALUE
      FROM ORD_HISTORY
     WHERE ORD.ID = ORD_HISTORY.ID
       AND ORD.DATE <= ORD_HISTORY.DATE
  ORDER BY ORD_HISTORY.DATE DESC
     LIMIT 1
   )   AS VALUE
FROM
  ORD
```

Comment: I tried the 1st solution is really slow for 7k records in ORD table. Really miss SQL SERVER.

Answer (score 31):

Starting from MySQL 8.0.14 you could use [`LATERAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-14.html#mysqld-8-0-14-sql-syntax):

> **A derived table now may be preceded by the LATERAL keyword to specify that it is permitted to refer to (depend on) columns of preceding tables in the same FROM clause.** A derived table specified with LATERAL can occur only in a FROM clause, either in a list of tables separated with commas or in a join specification (JOIN, INNER JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT [OUTER] JOIN, or RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN). Lateral derived tables make possible certain SQL operations that cannot be done with nonlateral derived tables or that require less-efficient workarounds

```
CROSS APPLY () <=> ,LATERAL ()
OUTER APPLY () <=> LEFT JOIN LATERAL () ON 1=1
```

[Support for LATERAL derived tables added to MySQL 8.0.14](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/support-for-lateral-derived-tables-added-to-mysql-8-0-14/)

And in this case:

```
SELECT ORD.ID
    ,ORD.NAME
    ,ORD.DATE
    ,ORD_HIST.VALUE
FROM ORD,
LATERAL (
    SELECT ORD_HISTORY.VALUE
    FROM ORD_HISTORY
    WHERE ORD.ID = ORD_HISTORY.ID
        AND ORD.DATE <= ORD_HISTORY.DATE
    ORDER BY ORD_HISTORY.DATE DESC
    LIMIT 1
    ) ORD_HIST;
```

If correlated subquery does not return any rows, the main row from main query will be skipped. In such scenario, `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` should be used.

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=21c1aa8db280669db4d2fa1ef682c746)**

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean with `LEFT JOIN LATERAL () ON 1=1`? That syntax does not work in MySql 8.0.18

Comment: @YvánEcarri Sure, added an example to illustrate this scenario.

Answer (score 6):

Based on @lujas szozda answer:

For the CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT ORD.ID
    ,ORD.NAME
    ,ORD.DATE
    ,ORD_HIST.VALUE
FROM ORD JOIN 
LATERAL (
    SELECT ORD_HISTORY.VALUE
    FROM ORD_HISTORY
    WHERE ORD.ID = ORD_HISTORY.ID
        AND ORD.DATE <= ORD_HISTORY.DATE
    ORDER BY ORD_HISTORY.DATE DESC
    LIMIT 1
    ) ORD_HIST ON 1=1
/* ON 1=1 is just a trick to join to whatever the LATERAL returns */
```

For the OUTER APPLY:

```
SELECT ORD.ID
    ,ORD.NAME
    ,ORD.DATE
    ,ORD_HIST.VALUE
FROM ORD LEFT JOIN 
LATERAL (
    SELECT ORD_HISTORY.VALUE
    FROM ORD_HISTORY
    WHERE ORD.ID = ORD_HISTORY.ID
        AND ORD.DATE <= ORD_HISTORY.DATE
    ORDER BY ORD_HISTORY.DATE DESC
    LIMIT 1
    ) ORD_HIST ON 1=1 
/* ON 1=1 is just a trick to join to whatever the LATERAL returns */
```