# JOIN with `greatest-n-per-group` and SUM in sub-query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

With over 1800 tagged questions for `greatest-n-per-group` and some excellent answers, I thought I'd find a solution to this one - but I've either missed the solution or I need a new approach.

I have a table `photo_types` to store votes by `user` who are voting (up or down) on what particular `photo_type` they think a given photo is.  Photo types are `1-10` and each vote will be `1` or `-1`.

```
+----+-----+-----------+------------+------+
| id | user | photo_id | photo_type | vote |
+----+------+----------+------------+------+
|  1 | jane |   photo1 |          1 |    1 |
|  2 | jane |   photo2 |          2 |    1 |
|  3 | jane |   photo3 |          4 |   -1 |
|  4 |  ben |   photo1 |          1 |    1 |
|  5 |  ben |   photo2 |          3 |   -1 |
|  6 |  ben |   photo2 |          2 |    1 |
|  7 | mary |   photo1 |          1 |   -1 |
|  8 | mary |   photo3 |         10 |    1 |
|  9 | mary |   photo2 |          1 |    1 |
| 10 | mary |   photo1 |          2 |   -1 |
+----+------+----------+------------+------+
```

I need to left join this table back to a `photos` table (that has all the other details of a given photo) - ***but only include the top 2 voted types*** for each photo.

The `photos` table to which I need to `LEFT JOIN` the `photo_types` table looks like:

```
+----+----------+------------+----------------+---------------+------------+
| id | photo_id | photo_name |   photographer |      location |       date |
+----+----------+------------+----------------+---------------+------------+
|  1 |   photo1 | the bridge |    Bill Murray |  Brooklyn, NY | 2012-10-11 |
|  2 |   photo2 |    the cat | Jacques Chirac | Paris, France | 2013-01-03 |
|  3 |   photo3 |      a car |     the Grinch |    London, UK | 2016-09-01 |
+----+----------+------------+----------------+---------------+------------+
```

I'm obviously joining the two tables via `photo_id`.

To get the top voted types for each photo I have tried a sub-query like this:

```
SELECT photo_id, photo_type, sum(vote) AS votes
FROM photo_types
GROUP BY photo_type, photo_id
HAVING votes>0
ORDER BY votes DESC
```

which groups the sum of the votes by `photo_type` as well as `photo_id`.
This works fine but includes all types with `sum(vote) > 0` - not just the top 2 voted types.
[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2029d8/1)

When included in the join it looks like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM photos
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT photo_id, photo_type, sum(vote) AS votes
    FROM photo_types
    GROUP BY photo_type, photo_id
    HAVING votes>0
    ORDER BY votes DESC) AS pt
ON photos.photo_id = pt.photo_id
WHERE photos.date > '2010-01-01';
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2029d8/7)

I had hoped to use [Bill Karwin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8749095/3092596) but I'm having trouble joining the table to itself based on the grouped values (which is a `SUM` in my case).  The sub-query I tried looked like :

```
SELECT pt1.*, SUM(pt1.vote) AS votes1, SUM(pt2.vote) AS votes2
FROM photo_types AS pt1
LEFT OUTER JOIN photo_types AS pt2
    ON pt1.photo_id = pt2.photo_id
        AND (votes1 < votes2
        OR (votes1 = votes2 AND pt1.id < pt2.id))
WHERE pt2.photo_id IS NULL
```

...which doesn't work because it's an attempt to join two tables on a calculated value (unlike Bill's solution).
[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2029d8/6)

**Question**
**Is there a way to get the `greatest-n-per-group` when the grouping is based on a calculated values such as `SUM(xxx)` ?**

Solutions which partially cover this are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/121450/3092596) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/123481/3092596) but don't include aggregates in the grouped values.

The other obvious way to do it is to simply re-calculate the highest voted values each time a vote is placed and store this directly in the `photos` table - [as discussed here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/239/storing-vs-calculating-aggregate-values) - but unless it's impossible - I'd prefer to calculate within the `SELECT` for various reasons.

Comment: Where's the desired result?

Comment: @Strawberry as per http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2029d8/7 but only include the top 2 voted types for each photo_id.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a limited list, the simplest way is the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
SELECT photo_id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(photo_type ORDER BY votes DESC), ',', 2) as top2
FROM (SELECT photo_id, photo_type, sum(vote) AS votes
      FROM photo_types
      GROUP BY photo_type, photo_id
      HAVING votes > 0
     ) pt
GROUP BY photo_id;
```

Notes:

- The intermediate string for `group_concat()` is about 1k -- which is more than enough for this problem.
- The alternatives (as you have discovered) either use variables for much more complex queries.

Comment: thanks - this does work - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2029d8/11 - but then won't work with a std `WHERE photo_type IN (array)` if I need to select based on `photo_type` - and probably requires a `REGEXP`. Any way to avoid comma separated values in the results ?

Answer (score 0):

Look up xxx apply functions. They give you much more flexibility than just doing sub aggregate queries.

```
http://sqlserverplanet.com/sql-2005/cross-apply-explained
```

Comment: thanks, interesting article but unfortunately `CROSS APPLY` doesn't exist in MySQL - and not entirely sure how to apply the approximation as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869221/cross-outer-apply-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

OK so from this [old blog post](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) (mentioned a few times in other `greatest-n-per-group` solutions), the following works :

```
SELECT pt1.*
FROM 
  (SELECT id, photo_id, photo_type, sum(vote) AS votes
  FROM photo_types
  GROUP BY photo_type, photo_id
  HAVING votes>0) AS pt1
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM 
    (SELECT id, photo_id, photo_type, sum(vote) AS votes
    FROM photo_types
    GROUP BY photo_type, photo_id
    HAVING votes>0) AS pt2
  WHERE pt1.photo_id = pt2.photo_id and pt1.votes <= pt2.votes
) <=2
ORDER BY photo_id, votes DESC
```

[see SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b27922/1)

However:
- not sure how efficient it is since it uses two subqueries
- won't return correct numbers of results if any of the `greatest-n` have identical values (since that pushes the count outside the specified limit) - as you can see [in this SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b1b57/2)