# SQL: Cross apply on MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, cross-apply

I try to run a query on SQL Server 2016 that need to get data from Mysql linked database.

```
SELECT o.*, name
FROM [DBS].[dbo].[Users] AS o WITH (NOLOCK) 
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT b.code FROM users.members b WHERE name = 'name') ou name
WHERE b.date > '2016-01-01'
```

How can I perform that kind of query with CROSS APPLY?

Comment: is cross apply supported in mysql?

Comment: I'm not sure, but what I'd like to know is how do I say SQL server that this sub-query need to be run on Mysql: SELECT b.code FROM users.members b WHERE name = 'name'

Comment: cross apply is not supported in mysql

Comment: check this case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869221/cross-outer-apply-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `CROSS APPLY` operator available in MySQL. In this case you can just use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT o.*, ou.code AS name
FROM [Users] AS o 
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT b.code 
   FROM users.members b 
   WHERE name = 'name') AS ou 
WHERE b.date > '2016-01-01'
```

Note that there was no need to do a `CROSS APPLY` in SQL Server either since there was no correlation in it.