# MySQL: Is there a better alternative to subquery in each left join

Tags: subquery, left-join, mariadb

My application needs to get some basic data from a `user` table with primary key `user_id` - and various other data about the user from secondary tables, each of which has `user_id` as a foreign key. There are a bunch of these secondary tables such as `name`, `addresss`, `phone`, etcetera - things about a person that can change over time.

More specifically, I need only some values from the *most recent row* from each secondary table.  Each table has a "latest" column which is unix timestamp of the most recent UPDATE or INSERT (we must not delete in this application).

The following works correctly:

```
SELECT u.username, u.user_id, u.password, u.email, u.active
    , n.first , n.middle , n.last
    , uo.organization_id  /* , other_cols_from_other_tables */
FROM user u
    LEFT JOIN user_org uo ON (uo.user_id = u.user_id AND
        uo.latest in (select max(latest) from name uo1
                      where uo1.user_id = u.user_id))
    /* here, other LEFT JOINs like the above one */
WHERE u.username = :username
```

However, a subquery solution is widely discouraged due to slowness, and some of these queries will run on every request.  So I came up with the following that works in some cases and gets rid of the subquery:

```
SELECT u.username, u.user_id, u.password, u.email, u.active
    , n.first , n.middle , n.last
    , uo.organization_id  /* , other_cols_from_other_tables, etc. */
FROM user u
    INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT user_id, MAX(latest) utd
        FROM user_org
        GROUP BY user_id
    ) uo1 ON uo1.user_id = u.user_id
    LEFT JOIN user_org uo
        ON (uo.user_id = u.user_id and uo.latest = uo1.utd)
    /* here, other clauses like the part from 'FROM' to here */
WHERE u.username = :username
```

The latter, unfortunately makes a hard dependence on data in the secondary table, so that the whole query fails if data is lacking in any secondary table for the particular user.

I've researched this on SO and www and there are *many* solutions for avoiding subqueries, but everything I've found on the subject has the issue in the main query, not in a left join.

The logic I need is "if there's data for this user in this secondary table, get the specified column(s) from the *most recent* row in that table, otherwise a null".

It seems to me that putting a "current row" marker column on the most recent row in each table would avoid the whole issue and run faster than any other solution, but would be against normalization (I would still have to have the 'latest' column to maintain order-able history of previous data).

Is there a solution that gets normalization + speed? This is mariadb so it needs Mysql syntax.

EDIT: Still would like a better way, but decided to go with the extra column. Now the problem described above is avoided, and the SELECT SQL is much simplified and presumably faster.  The downside is adding complexity in saves, but SELECT is more frequent.

Comment: Unfortunately mySQL doesn't yet support analytical functions (use a RowNumber limit to 1 ordered by your latest) or cross/Outer  apply with a limit 1.  There is a way to simulate it similar to what you've done however: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869221/cross-outer-apply-in-mysql

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` or `RANK` would be great, but MySQL doesn't support them. `CROSS APPLY` to fetch the last related row would be great, but MySQL doesn't support it. `MAX/MIN KEEP LAST` would be great, but MySQL doesn't support it. So what remains are the approaches you are showing. If it's only one column/value that you need from a table, however, you can use a correlated subquery in the `SELECT` clause with `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: **EDIT:** You say you are using MariaDB? Why did you tag MySQL then? As of version 10.2 MariaDB supports window functions such as `ROW_NUMBER` or `RANK`.

Comment: I've changed the tag from MySQL to MariaDB.

Comment: There is a lot more documentation on Mysql, and Mariadb was supposed to be a drop-in replacement so that it would all apply, so I thought it more helpful to searchers to tag it with 'Mysql'.  This feature being different however, suggests that divergence is starting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MariaDB supports `ROW_NUMBER` as of version 10.2:

```
SELECT 
  u.username, 
  u.user_id, 
  u.password, 
  u.email, 
  u.active,
  uo.organization_id,
  ...
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN
(
  select
    user_org.*,
    row_number() over(partition by user_id order by latest desc) as rn
  from user_org
) uo ON uo.user_id = u.user_id AND uo.rn = 1
...
WHERE u.username = :username;
```