# LEFT JOIN but with additional rows from parent table

Tags: mysql, join, cross-join

Not sure what to call this, -- I'm sure this has to be asked elsewhere.

Consider the following, eg.

```
CREATE TABLE abbrv (
    abbrv_id int unsigned primary key not null auto_increment,
    usps_primary varchar(64) not null,
    usps_preferred varchar(16) not null
);

CREATE TABLE abbrv_variation (
    variation_id int unsigned primary key not null auto_increment,
    abbrv_id int unsigned, -- FK
    variation varchar(64) not null
);

INSERT INTO abbrv(usps_primary, usps_preferred) VALUES('North', 'N');
INSERT INTO abbrv(usps_primary, usps_preferred) VALUES('South', 'S');
INSERT INTO abbrv(usps_primary, usps_preferred) VALUES('East', 'E');
INSERT INTO abbrv(usps_primary, usps_preferred) VALUES('West', 'W');

INSERT INTO `abbrv` (usps_primary, usps_preferred) values('ALLEY', 'ALY');
SET @abbrvId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO `abbrv_variation` (abbrv_id, variation) VALUES(@abbrvId, 'ALLEE');
INSERT INTO `abbrv_variation` (abbrv_id, variation) VALUES(@abbrvId, 'ALLY');

INSERT INTO `abbrv` (usps_primary, usps_preferred) values('ANEX', 'ANX');
SET @abbrvId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO `abbrv_variation` (abbrv_id, variation) VALUES(@abbrvId, 'ANNEX');
INSERT INTO `abbrv_variation` (abbrv_id, variation) VALUES(@abbrvId, 'ANNX');
INSERT INTO `abbrv_variation` (abbrv_id, variation) VALUES(@abbrvId, 'ANX');
```

What I am simply trying to do is return something such as:

```
+--------------+----------------+-----------+
| usps_primary | usps_preferred | variation |
+--------------+----------------+-----------+
| North        | N              | North     | <-- 1 row for "usps_primary"
| North        | N              | N         | <-- 1 row for "usps_preferred"
| South        | S              | South     | <-- 1 row for "usps_primary"
| South        | S              | S         | <-- 1 row for "usps_preferred"
| East         | E              | East      | <-- 1 row for "usps_primary"
| East         | E              | E         | <-- 1 row for "usps_preferred"
| West         | W              | West      | <-- 1 row for "usps_primary"
| West         | W              | W         | <-- 1 row for "usps_preferred"
| ALLEY        | ALY            | ALLEY     | <-- 1 row for "usps_primary"
| ALLEY        | ALY            | ALY       | <-- 1 row for "usps_preferred"
| ALLEY        | ALY            | ALLEE     | X-- one row for each 
| ALLEY        | ALY            | ALLY      | X-- variation    
| ANEX         | ANX            | ANEX      | <-- 1 row for "usps_primary"
| ANEX         | ANX            | ANX       | <-- 1 row for "usps_preferred"
| ANEX         | ANX            | ANNEX     | X-- one row for each 
| ANEX         | ANX            | ANNX      | X-- variation
```

The ordering doesn't matter - just that they're all there.  Originally this table simply had the "variation" rows for each of these but it's became unmaintainable as it's a very large table to make sure all these rows are entered each time there is a new variation added.

I've tried of course a simple LEFT JOIN, CROSS JOINs, OUTER JOINs, Joining some left and some right - I really don't know what the appropriate course of action here is, at all.

A cross join seems approximately correct but I do not want the entire  series, just 2x each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT usps_primary, usps_preferred, usps_primary AS variation FROM abbrv
UNION
SELECT usps_primary, usps_preferred, usps_preferred FROM abbrv
UNION
SELECT a.usps_primary, a.usps_preferred, v.variation FROM abbrv AS a 
INNER JOIN abbrv_variation AS v USING (abbrv_id)
ORDER BY usps_primary
```

Output:

```
+--------------+----------------+-----------+
| usps_primary | usps_preferred | variation |
+--------------+----------------+-----------+
| ALLEY        | ALY            | ALLEY     |
| ALLEY        | ALY            | ALLEE     |
| ALLEY        | ALY            | ALLY      |
| ALLEY        | ALY            | ALY       |
| ANEX         | ANX            | ANX       |
| ANEX         | ANX            | ANNX      |
| ANEX         | ANX            | ANEX      |
| ANEX         | ANX            | ANNEX     |
| East         | E              | E         |
| East         | E              | East      |
| North        | N              | North     |
| North        | N              | N         |
| South        | S              | South     |
| South        | S              | S         |
| West         | W              | W         |
| West         | W              | West      |
+--------------+----------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`LATERAL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54467105/5070879):

```
SELECT usps_primary, usps_preferred, s.variation
FROM abbrv a
,LATERAL(SELECT a.usps_primary AS variation
         UNION SELECT a.usps_preferred 
         UNION SELECT av.variation FROM abbrv_variation av WHERE a.abbrv_id = av.abbrv_id) s
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=858d877314c6a853002896d1bd2f5017)**

Output:

```
+---------------+-----------------+-----------+
| usps_primary  | usps_preferred  | variation |
+---------------+-----------------+-----------+
| North         | N               | North     |
| North         | N               | N         |
| South         | S               | South     |
| South         | S               | S         |
| East          | E               | East      |
| East          | E               | E         |
| West          | W               | West      |
| West          | W               | W         |
| ALLEY         | ALY             | ALLEY     |
| ALLEY         | ALY             | ALY       |
| ALLEY         | ALY             | ALLEE     |
| ALLEY         | ALY             | ALLY      |
| ANEX          | ANX             | ANEX      |
| ANEX          | ANX             | ANX       |
| ANEX          | ANX             | ANNEX     |
| ANEX          | ANX             | ANNX      |
+---------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

Comment: @mangusta There is no point it was first attempt.I left final answer :D