# JOIN a table by SELECT subquery with LIMIT 1 and WHERE clause matching column values outside of it

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I'm trying to JOIN a table with a subquery to limit data to only 1 last row, matching certain values from other FROM or JOINed tables:

```
SELECT

  t1.column1,
  t1.column2,
  t2.column1,
  t3.column2

FROM

  table1 t1

JOIN 
(
    SELECT column1 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE t1.column2 > table2.column1
    ORDER BY table2.date DESC
    LIMIT 1

) t2 

JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.column1=t3.column2
```

Getting an error: Unknown column t1.column2 in 'where clause'. Seems I can't address other columns inside the subquery.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?
If so, what am I doing wrong / what other way could I try this?

Comment: Put there `WHERE` clause in the outer-query.

Comment: I need to join only a single row, not the whole table. Putting the where clause outside would include all possible matches from the JOINed table, but I only need a specific one. @Dai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was:

```
SELECT

  t1.column1,
  t1.column2,
  t2.column1,
  t3.column2

FROM

  table1 t1

JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = 
(
    SELECT id 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE t1.column2 > table2.column1
    ORDER BY table2.date DESC
    LIMIT 1
) 

JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.column1=t3.column2
```

More info on:

[CROSS/OUTER APPLY in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869221/cross-outer-apply-in-mysql)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/170760/13156

Answer (score 0):

You may re-write your query as -

```
SELECT t1.column1,
       t1.column2,
       t2.column1,
       t3.column2
FROM table1 t1
JOIN (SELECT column1 
      FROM table2
      ORDER BY table2.date DESC
      LIMIT 1) t2 ON t1.column2 > t2.column1
JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.column1=t3.column2
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! The value t2.column1 is blank, SELECT column1 FROM table2 LIMIT 1 would only join the first row from t2, regardless of filtering the data? Note that I've slightly edited the query in my question

Comment: @IvanIvković, Please try now.

Comment: found the solution, you may check the new answer

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, implicit and explicit joins together in a single query create the problem. You can not use an implicit `JOIN` based on a nested `SELECT - FROM - WHERE` query when there is another explicit `JOIN` present.

Try below.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN  table2 t2 ON t1.column2 > t2.column1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.column1=t3.column2
```

Comment: The problem is I need to join only the last row matching a few parameters, not the whole table.