# MYSQL 5: Returning expression if statement is false, similar to NULLIF

Tags: mysql, sql, string, mysql5, sql-null

I have a long complicated expression that refers to multiple tables. The expression returns a string, but i want to return a different string if the returned string was empty "".

With the IF function i have to write my expression twice like:

```
IF(*expression* = "", "string not found", *expression*)
```

I know that NULLIF has something close to what i want as:

```
NULLIF(*expression*, "")
```

would return my expression if it was not empty, but if it was empty, it would return NULL, rather than a costum string.

Is there any way to avoid duplicating the expression, while still being able to choose a custom return string instead of just null, since duplicating the expressions (i have several cases of this in my query) would make the view-quera virtually unreadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fine with converting `null` values as well, you can mix `NULLIF()` and `COALESCE()`:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(expression, ''), 'string not found')
```

Comment: Yes of course. I don't know why i did not think of this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`LATERAL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869221/cross-outer-apply-in-mysql/54467105#54467105):

```
SELECT IF(s.col = '', 'string not found', s.col)
FROM tab
,LATERAL (SELECT complex_expr AS col) s  -- LATERAL could be chained
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aab78398e472a5046fd2d04f5a616877)**

But this only in MySQL 8.0+. Alternative is a suqbquery:

```
SELECT IF(s.col = '', 'string not found', s.col)
FROM (SELECT complex_expr AS col
      FROM tab) s
```

Comment: Thanks. But i found the above solution better for me.
I know about the possibilities in MySQL 8, however i am forced to use MySQL 5 for this