# select maximum date of multiple dates

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I get the number of rows of maximum creation dates?

Example data:

```
id|code|transaction_date   |amount|record_status|creation_date
1 |0001|2021-12-10 00:00:00| 10.00|D            |2021-12-10 00:00:00
2 |0001|2021-12-10 00:00:00| 10.00|D            |2021-12-11 10:00:00
3 |0002|2021-12-11 00:00:00| 10.00|D            |2021-12-11 00:00:00
4 |0002|2021-12-11 00:00:00| 10.00|D            |2021-12-12 10:00:00
```

I want to get this:

```
id|code|transaction_date   |amount|record_status|creation_date
2 |0001|2021-12-10 00:00:00| 10.00|D            |2021-12-11 10:00:00
4 |0002|2021-12-11 00:00:00| 10.00|D            |2021-12-12 10:00:00
```

I am trying this

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE (SELECT max(creation_date) from table1 WHERE DATE(transaction_date) = '2021-12-10')
AND record_status = 'D';
```

But I won't be able to select a range of date like I want `IN ('2021-12-10', 2021-12-11')`

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: I am using mysql 5

Comment: Does `(code,creation_date)` is defined as unique? If not then what output do you need in the case when more than one row contains the same maximal `creation_date`?

Comment: Are you after the maximum creation date for each code?  if so `Lateral` is the table function you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869221/cross-outer-apply-in-mysql  or a coorleated subquery with a limit or an analytic.  This could also be accomplished by assigning a row number for each partition of code ordering by creation date descending and then limiting by the row number 1 in an outer query.  Take your pick... each works offers similar performance; and depending on data/structure some are slightly faster.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE  table1 (
 id int,
 code int,
 transaction_date datetime,
 amount decimal(10,2),
 record_status varchar(2),
 creation_date datetime );

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES

(1,0001,'2021-12-10 00:00:00',10.00,'D','2021-12-10 00:00:00'),
(2,0001,'2021-12-10 00:00:00',10.00,'D','2021-12-11 10:00:00'),
(3,0002,'2021-12-11 00:00:00',10.00,'D','2021-12-11 00:00:00'),
(4,0002,'2021-12-11 00:00:00',10.00,'D','2021-12-12 10:00:00'),
(5,0003,'2021-12-10 00:00:00',10.00,'D','2021-12-11 10:00:00'),
(6,0003,'2021-12-10 00:00:00',10.00,'D','2021-12-16 10:00:00');



SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.creation_date = ( SELECT  MAX(t2.creation_date)
                           FROM table1 t2
                           WHERE t2.code = t1.code
                         );
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> id    code    transaction_date    amount  record_status   creation_date
> 2 1   2021-12-10 00:00:00 10.00   D   2021-12-11 10:00:00
> 4 2   2021-12-11 00:00:00 10.00   D   2021-12-12 10:00:00
> 6 3   2021-12-10 00:00:00 10.00   D   2021-12-16 10:00:00
> ```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3b59835d81c67bc7b366ecce815ce67d

Comment: Possible to only select a range of transaction_date?

Comment: @Alvin You could add the  `transaction_date` in a `where` condition inside the subquery of getting the max creation time. Try with your data and let me know if it helps

Comment: You need a correlated subquery to ensure the correct result.

Comment: This works for the example data shown, but it won't work for all data, because another `code` may have a date matching one of those returned by the subquery even though it isn't the max date for that `code`.

Answer (score 1):

For using a range you can use between, like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE creation_date IN (
SELECT max(creation_date) from table1
WHERE record_status = 'D'
   AND creation_date between '2021-12-11'
   AND '2021-12-13'
group by DATE(transaction_date))
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fb788/10)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like?

```sql
SELECT `table1`.*
FROM `table1`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `code`, MAX(`creation_date`) AS `max_date`
    FROM `table1`
    WHERE `record_status` = 'D'
    GROUP BY `code`
) `latest`
    ON `table1`.`code` = `latest`.`code`
    AND `table1`.`creation_date` = `latest`.`max_date`
```

This uses a derived table to get the max date per code.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM table t2
                   WHERE t1.code = t2.code
                     AND t1.creation_date < t2.creation_date
                  /* AND t2.record_status = 'D' 
                     AND t2.DATE(transaction_date) = '2021-12-10' */ )
/* AND record_status = 'D'
   AND DATE(transaction_date) = '2021-12-10' */ ;
```