# How to convert SQL Server query to MySQL (OUTER APPLY)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to switch from SQL Server to MySQL, hence some queries need to be converted.

The following SQL Server query gives my desired output:

```
SELECT top 20 c.ID as Pid, c.CustomerNumber, c.Name, c.Surname, c.Area, c.City, c.Address, c.PhoneNumber, c.CustomerTypeID, c.Enabled, c.DateCreated, p.Id, p.Debit, p.Credit
FROM TblCustomer c OUTER APPLY
(
SELECT TOP 1 p.*
FROM TblPayments p
WHERE c.CustomerNumber = p.CustomerNumber
ORDER BY p.id DESC
)
p
```

The output is in the following <link: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/10n0VJn59OlzT-pyVtXXx197EAuStBvwh/view?usp=sharing>](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10n0VJn59OlzT-pyVtXXx197EAuStBvwh/view?usp=sharing%3E)

I am trying the following MySQL query, however it is not what I am looking for:

```
SELECT c.CustomerNumber, c.ID, c.Name, c.Surname, c.Area, c.City, c.Address, c.PhoneNumber, c.CustomerTypeID, c.Enabled, c.DateCreated, p.Id, p.Debit, p.Credit
FROM TblCustomer as c
join TblPayments as p
on c.CustomerNumber = p.CustomerNumber
order by p.Id DESC
limit  20
```

The output of MySQL is the following: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11sKHPt3xI6qKUdF3bCL_kZGr8EeX7pts/view?usp=sharing

Description of output: Each customer from TblCustomer (top 20) with its respective Id from TblPayment (latest invoice Id).

Can someone help me to convert the first query (SQL Server) to MySQL query?

Comment: I can see that the problem here on MSSQL you're doing `top 20` while `ORDER BY p.Id DESC LIMIT 20` in MySQL - that is not really a top 20 in MySQL part. The top 20 is based on which column? That's where you should do your `ORDER BY column_name DESC LIMIT 20`.

Comment: Let me try and clarify a bit more @FanoFN . Top 20 is not important, I am doing top 20 for efficiency purposes. I need to get all the clients from the first table (TblCustomer) and their last invoiceId from table 2 (TblPayment). Meaning, one client, one row. I want to get the client + their last invoice, because from there I get their balance (debit/credit).

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version? OUTER APPLY in SQL Server == LATERAL JOIN in recent MySQl versions.

Comment: *The following MSSQL query gives my desired output* This is **NOT** a query, this is some code which composes it. Show final query text.

Comment: That's a lot simpler then. Depending on your MySQL version, you might need to do `JOIN` once or twice to get the result. You can check MySQL version by running `SELECT version();`

Comment: In your MySQL statement is missing an eqivalent for `SELECT TOP 1` in the inner statement.

Comment: Precise MySQL version 8.0.28. I am using JDBCTemplate in Spring Boot app. The query in MSSQL is as per the updated question now. So if someone can help me how to compose the query in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer from @Lukasz Szozda from the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/54467105/14405988 and the suggestion from @Akina I reached my desired outcome with the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.CustomerNumber, c.Name, c.Surname, c.Area, c.City, c.Address, c.PhoneNumber, c.CustomerTypeID, c.Enabled, c.DateCreated, p.Id, p.Debit, p.Credit
FROM TblCustomer c, LATERAL
(
SELECT p.*
FROM TblPayments p
WHERE c.CustomerNumber = p.CustomerNumber
ORDER BY p.id DESC
LIMIT 1)
p
limit 20
```