# MySQL equivalent to SQL Server's Cross Apply Values Keyword

Tags: mysql, sql-server

```
    cross apply (
    values
        (col1_id, col1_amt),
        (col2_id, col2_amt),
        (col3_id, col3_amt),
        (col4_id, col4_amt),
        (col5_id, col5_amt),
        (col6_id, col6_amt)
) e (col_id, col_amt)
```

I want equivalent of this SQL Server syntax in MySQL but can't seem to find any ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Not true as of MySQL 8+, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869221/cross-outer-apply-in-mysql).  MySQL now supports lateral joins.

Comment: i have checked lateral but it seems it does not know values syntax ?

Comment: *it does not know values syntax* Use SELECT instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`CROSS JOIN LATERAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html) in MySQL 8.0.14+. [`VALUES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html) is also supported from 8.0.19+ (but you need a `ROW` constructor)

```sql
select *
from (values
    row('a')
) v1(x)
cross join lateral (values
    row (concat(v1.x, 'b'))
) v2(y)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=836e7947e22f018af0a6018ae0e3907d)

---

So for your example, you can do this

```sql
cross join lateral
(
    values
    row(fund1_id, fund1_amt),
    row(fund2_id, fund2_amt),
    row(fund3_id, fund3_amt),
    row(fund4_id, fund4_amt),
    row(fund5_id, fund5_amt),
    row(fund6_id, fund6_amt)
)
```

---

For an `OUTER APPLY` you can use `LEFT JOIN LATERAL .... ON 1=1`

Comment: can you check if you can use values inside lataral scope

Comment: Yes it is, have modified

Comment: SELECT .. UNION ALL is more simple than VALUES .. ROW().

Comment: @Akina can you share sample ?

Comment: ```cross join lateral ( values row (concat(v1.x, 'b')) ) v2(y)``` is an equivalent for ```cross join lateral ( SELECT concat(v1.x, 'b') ) v2(y)```. And you may expand this with UNION ALL, for example, ```cross join lateral ( SELECT concat(v1.x, 'b') UNION ALL SELECT concat(v1.x, 'c') ) v2(y)```.

Comment: @Desmond_ 1) Insert this link into the question text 2) Add source table - structure and some data.

Comment: as this this is sensitive dont want to share it btw

Comment: @Desmond_ What exactly is the question? Change `CROSS APPLY` to `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` and add `ROW` in front of each row

Comment: @Charlieface check the dbfiddle link please i have shared the sql query there

Comment: the question is i just want to changes values inside the cross apply with mysql syntax should i replace values with ROW ?

Comment: OK have modified further

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `ROW` before every row:

```
cross apply (
    values
        ROW(col1_id, col1_amt),
        ROW(col2_id, col2_amt),
        ROW(col3_id, col3_amt),
        ROW(col4_id, col4_amt),
        ROW(col5_id, col5_amt),
        ROW(col6_id, col6_amt)
) e (col_id, col_amt)
```

EDIT: A simple example to show how `VALUES` and `ROW` should work is this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=70ac2b7f5ee51b95f9cd2f5b22102e93)

Comment: it does not work

Comment: @Desmond_ "does not work" is not an useful comment. People are trying to help YOU - make an effort to provide useful information.

Comment: I added a (simple!) example of how VALUES and ROW should work in MySQL