# CROSS APPLY in Oracle/SQL Server substitute in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking for the best alternatives on mapping Cross APPLY to SF.

Something like:

```sql
select department_name, employee_id, employee_name
from   departments d
       cross apply (select employee_id, employee_name
                    from   employees e
                    where  salary >= 2000
                    and    e.department_id = d.department_id)
order by 1, 2, 3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANSI SQL equivalent of `CROSS APPLY` is `JOIN LATERAL`:

```
select department_name, employee_id, employee_name
from   departments d
join lateral (select employee_id, employee_name
                           from   employees e
                           where  salary >= 2000
                           and    e.department_id = d.department_id)
order by 1, 2, 3;
```

Output:

[image]

and for `OUTER APPLY` is `LEFT JOIN LATERAL () ON TRUE`:

```
select department_name, employee_id, employee_name
from   departments d
left join lateral (select employee_id, employee_name
                           from   employees e
                           where  salary >= 2000
                           and    e.department_id = d.department_id) ON TRUE
order by 1, 2, 3;
```

Output:

[image]

---

For source data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE departments(department_id INT, department_name TEXT,
                                    deparment_location TEXT)
AS
SELECT 1, 'HR',       'London' UNION
SELECT 2, 'SALES',    'Berlin' UNION
SELECT 3, 'RESEARCH', 'Paris';

 
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE  employees(employee_id INT, employee_name TEXT, 
                                   salary INT, department_id INT)
AS 
SELECT 100, 'John', 2000, 1 UNION
SELECT 101, 'Anna', 4000, 2;
```

---

Related: [CROSS/OUTER APPLY in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54467105/5070879)

Answer (score 0):

What I have seen is that the same results can be achieved with a CROSS JOIN LATERAL

using this testdata from [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1):

```sql
create table departments (
  department_id   number(2) ,
  department_name varchar2(14),
  location        varchar2(13)
);

insert into departments values (10,'ACCOUNTING','NEW YORK');
insert into departments values (20,'RESEARCH','DALLAS');
insert into departments values (30,'SALES','CHICAGO');
insert into departments values (40,'OPERATIONS','BOSTON');



create table employees (
  employee_id   number(4) ,
  employee_name varchar2(10),
  job           varchar2(9),
  manager_id    number(4),
  hiredate      date,
  salary        number(7,2),
  commission    number(7,2),
  department_id number(2) 
);

insert into employees values (7369,'SMITH','CLERK',7902,to_date('17-12-1980','dd-mm-yyyy'),800,NULL,20);
insert into employees values (7499,'ALLEN','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('20-2-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),1600,300,30);
insert into employees values (7521,'WARD','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('22-2-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),1250,500,30);
insert into employees values (7566,'JONES','MANAGER',7839,to_date('2-4-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),2975,NULL,20);
insert into employees values (7654,'MARTIN','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('28-9-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),1250,1400,30);
insert into employees values (7698,'BLAKE','MANAGER',7839,to_date('1-5-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),2850,NULL,30);
insert into employees values (7782,'CLARK','MANAGER',7839,to_date('9-6-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),2450,NULL,10);
insert into employees values (7788,'SCOTT','ANALYST',7566,to_date('13-JUL-87','dd-mm-rr')-85,3000,NULL,20);
insert into employees values (7839,'KING','PRESIDENT',NULL,to_date('17-11-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),5000,NULL,10);
insert into employees values (7844,'TURNER','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('8-9-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),1500,0,30);
insert into employees values (7876,'ADAMS','CLERK',7788,to_date('13-6-87', 'dd-mm-yyyy')-51,1100,NULL,20);
insert into employees values (7900,'JAMES','CLERK',7698,to_date('3-12-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),950,NULL,30);
insert into employees values (7902,'FORD','ANALYST',7566,to_date('3-12-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),3000,NULL,20);
insert into employees values (7934,'MILLER','CLERK',7782,to_date('23-1-1982','dd-mm-yyyy'),1300,NULL,10);
```

As mentioned in the question, the following:

```sql
select department_name, employee_id, employee_name
from   departments d
       cross join lateral (select employee_id, employee_name
                           from   employees e
                           where  salary >= 2000
                           and    e.department_id = d.department_id)
order by 1, 2, 3;
```

is equivalent, but is it the best option?