# Time difference between start/stop interactions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my database that looks like this

learner_lessons

```
learnerlessonid    learnerid    lessonid 
      1                24           42
```

learner_lesson_logs

```
lessonlogid     learnerlessonid   progress   maxprogress    interaction   createdAt 
1                       1            0          15            Start      2022-11-02 07:51:30                    
2                       1            4          15            Pause      2022-11-02 07:51:34 
3                       1            4          15            Play       2022-11-02 07:52:20 
4                       1            14         15            Run        2022-11-02 07:52:30     
5                       1            15         15            Stop       2022-11-02 07:52:31
```

Basically, when a user clicks on a video it starts playing and the interaction is recorded as 'Start' and a timestamp is created accordingly. Now when a user pauses the video another interaction 'Pause' is created and the timestamp is recorded. The user might come back later and resume the video thus creating a 'Play' interaction. After every 10 seconds of the video if it isn't paused another interaction 'Run' is logged in the database. Finally when the video ends 'Stop' interaction is created.

What I am aiming to achieve is the difference in timestamps when a video is 'Started' or 'Played' till the video is 'Paused' or 'Stopped'. The interactions could be 'Start', and 'Stop' as well.

This is the query I am working on now

```
select ll.learnerId ,lll.createdAt,
       (case when interactionType = 'Start' or interactionType  = 'Play'
             then DATEDIFF(SECOND,
                           lll.createdAt,
                           (case when interactionType = 'Stop' or interactionType = 'Pause' then lll.createdAt end) over (order by lll.createdAt desc)
                          )
        end) as diff_minutes
from learner_lesson_log lll join learner_lessons ll on ll.learnerLessonId = lll.learnerLessonId 
order by lll.createdAt
```

But is throwing me the error

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
> the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near '(order by createdAt desc)
> )
> end) as diff_minut' at line 5
>
> Error position: line: 4

I want the end result to look like this for each learner

```
learnerid      Length of interaction      start_timestamp
24                  4                     2022-11-02 07:51:30
24                  11                    2022-11-02 07:52:20
```

Comment: Your OVER clause have no according window function...

Comment: *the difference in timestamps when a video is 'Started' or 'Played' till the video is 'Paused' or 'Stopped'* If a timeline is Started-Played-Paused-Stopped then the difference(s) between what points must be calculated?

Comment: @Akina There's no interaction where the video is Started-Played-Paused-Stopped, the combination that could occur is Started-Started in case the learner didn't pause the video and just refreshed the page. But in that case we don't need to count the time difference. The difference should be counted only when the video is either 'Started' / 'Played' till the vide is either 'Paused'/ 'Stopped'. So 'Started' -> 'Stop' can be a possible interaction so does 'Play' and 'Pause'

Comment: *There's no interaction where the video is Started-Played-Paused-Stopped* What provides this integrity rule, what constraint is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using **MySQL version >= 8.0.14**, you can use a [**LATERAL DERIVED TABLE**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54467105/3092847) to get the next `createdAt` date that you need to make your comparison in `SECONDS` between your `interactionType's`.

```
SELECT 
  c.learnerid AS "Learner ID",
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, a.createdAt, NextDate) AS "Length of Interaction",
  a.createdAt AS "Start Timestamp"
FROM learner_lesson_log a 
  INNER JOIN learner_lessons c 
  ON c.learnerLessonId = a.learnerLessonId, 
LATERAL (
SELECT b.createdAt AS NextDate,
       b.interactionType AS NextType
                  FROM learner_lesson_log b
            INNER JOIN learner_lessons d 
                    ON b.learnerLessonId = d.learnerLessonId
                 WHERE b.learnerLessonId = a.learnerLessonId
                   AND d.learnerId = c.learnerId
                   AND b.createdAt > a.createdAt
                   AND b.interactionType IN ('Stop', 'Pause')
              ORDER BY b.createdAt ASC LIMIT 1
    ) bb
WHERE a.interactionType IN ('Start', 'Play') 
ORDER BY a.createdAt ASC;
```

**Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/zf2A9W-1).**

For your version, **MySQL version 5.7**, use a `subquery` in the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` calculation:

```
SELECT 
  c.learnerid AS "Learner ID",
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, a.createdAt, 
  (SELECT b.createdAt
                  FROM learner_lesson_log b
            INNER JOIN learner_lessons d 
                    ON b.learnerLessonId = d.learnerLessonId
                 WHERE b.learnerLessonId = a.learnerLessonId
                   AND d.learnerId = c.learnerId
                   AND b.createdAt > a.createdAt
                   AND b.interactionType IN ('Stop', 'Pause')
              ORDER BY b.createdAt ASC LIMIT 1)) AS "Length of Interaction",
  a.createdAt AS "Start Timestamp"
FROM learner_lesson_log a 
INNER JOIN learner_lessons c 
  ON c.learnerLessonId = a.learnerLessonId 
WHERE a.interactionType IN ('Start', 'Play') 
ORDER BY a.createdAt ASC;
```

**Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Yo3-CAq7).**

**Result:**

| Learner ID | Length of Interaction | Start Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 4 | 2022-11-02 07:51:30 |
| 24 | 11 | 2022-11-02 07:52:20 |

Comment: Hi @griv sorry, I keep looking at the query but can't figure out what's going on here., can you describe a bit on how the tables are joined as there are 2 instances of each table

Comment: Sure, I essentially did the same JOIN (in the inner subquery used in the TIMESTAMPDIFF parameter and the outer query). The only difference is the WHERE clause in the subquery using keys from the outer query. A good metric of figuring out what's happening is take the subquery out and run it by itself to see what its doing. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
select   learnerid
        ,max(createdAt)-min(createdAt) as Length_of_interaction
        ,min(createdAt)                as start_timestamp
from
(
select   *
        ,count(case when interaction in('Pause', 'Stop') then 1 end) over(partition by learnerid order by createdAt desc) as grp
from     learner_lessons l1 join learner_lesson_logs l2 using(learnerlessonid)
) l3
group by learnerid, grp
order by start_timestamp
```

| learnerid | Length_of_interaction | start_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 4 | 2022-11-02 07:51:30 |
| 24 | 11 | 2022-11-02 07:52:20 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-RzzD3T4)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I am using the 5.7 version of MySQL and cannot update the database due to some restrictions. It show's the error 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by learnerid order by createdAt desc) as grp
from     learner_lessons' at line 7' in the fiddle as well

Comment: @hyeri you should consider upgrading regardless of your restrictions (I also don't know what restrictions would justify not upgrading but I'll leave that up to you). @DannySlor, it seems as though the `length_of_interaction` is not calculating correctly when I add more `learnerid`'s and `learnerlessonid`'s, compare it with my answer in v8 here: https://dbfiddle.uk/6TLTbUef

Comment: Also, a little explanation of the query would be super helpful. A million thanks in advance :)

Comment: @GRIV The developers who have created the database and linked it to the site do not want any changes at the moment. :(

Comment: @hyeri that is a shame, besides getting a plethora of new functions and features, there are vulnerabilities in older versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for MySQL 5.7. We just extract the start and end time for each section. Then, without using a window function, we generate row_number and use integral math to pair up each start and and end time in a group.

```
select   learnerid
        ,max(flg)-min(flg) as Length_of_interaction
        ,min(flg)          as start_timestamp    
from
        (
         select    learnerlessonid
                  ,case when interaction not in('Run') then createdAt end as flg
         from      learner_lesson_logs l2 
         where     case when interaction not in('Run') then createdAt end is not null
         order by  createdAt
         ) t       
         join learner_lessons using(learnerlessonid) join (select @rn := 0) i
group by learnerid, ceiling((@rn := @rn + 1)/2) 
order by start_timestamp
```

| learnerid | Length_of_interaction | start_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 4 | 2022-11-02 07:51:30 |
| 24 | 11 | 2022-11-02 07:52:20 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/N4ee9f4f)